# Need to close out java with the letter q

Tags: java, exit, halt

I'm pretty new to programming. I need it to say "Enter the letter q to quit or any other key to continue: " at the end. If you enter q, it terminates. If you enter any other character, it prompts you to enter another positive integer.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TimesTable {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


       System.out.println("Enter a postive integer: ");
       int tableSize = input.nextInt();
       printMultiplicationTable(tableSize);

    }
    public static void printMultiplicationTable(int tableSize) {
        System.out.format("      ");
        for(int i = 1; i<=tableSize;i++ ) {
            System.out.format("%4d",i);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("------------------------------------------------");

        for(int i = 1 ;i<=tableSize;i++) {
            System.out.format("%4d |",i);
            for(int j=1;j<=tableSize;j++) {
                System.out.format("%4d",i*j);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: a while loop with `String q` check will do your job

Answer (score 0):

Do this to have the user input a letter

Info:

System.exit(0) exits the program with no error code.

nextLine() waits for user to enter string and press enter.

 nextInt() waits for user to enter int and press enter.

Hope this helps!

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String i = input.nextLine();
if(i.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
    System.exit(0);
}else {
    System.out.println("Enter a postive integer: ");
    int i = input.nextInt();
    //continue with your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like homework ;-)

One way to solve this problem is to put your code that prints your messages and accepts your input inside a while loop, maybe something like:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
byte nextByte = 0x00;
while(nextByte != 'q') 
{     
    System.out.println("Enter a postive integer: ");
    int tableSize = input.nextInt();
    printMultiplicationTable(tableSize);
    System.out.println("Enter q to quit, or any other key to continue... ");
    nextByte = input.nextByte();
}
```

Comment: Stephen, i tried using your solution, but it won't allow me to use q or any other characters after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

use a **do-while** loop in your main method as below

```
do {
        System.out.println("Enter a postive integer: ");
        String tableSize = input.next();

        if (!"q".equals(tableSize) )
            printMultiplicationTable(Integer.parseInt(tableSize));

    }while (!"q".equals(input.next()));
    input.close();
```

you would also want to have a **try-catch** block to handle numberFormatException

Comment: This worked pretty well. Now all I need is for it to say "Enter q to quit or any other character to continue: " Below the table